# stripe paymentIntent creation passing to front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a `paymentIntent`.
I successfully created it but it is not being passed to the front end properly, stripe support is garbage so I figured I would ask here.

This is my node code:

```
//the node.js for creating payment intent:


exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {

    let TOTAL = event["POST"]["amount"];
    let AMOUNT = (TOTAL * 100);
    let FEE = (AMOUNT * 0.03).toFixed(0);
    let stripeAccount = event["POST"]["stripeAccount"];


    const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: AMOUNT,
        currency: "usd",
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        metadata: {
            integration_check: 'accept_a_payment'
        },
        application_fee_amount: FEE,
        on_behalf_of: stripeAccount,
        transfer_data: {
            destination: stripeAccount
        }


    });

    console.log(paymentIntent)
    clientSecret = paymentIntent.client_secret;
    callback(null, clientSecret)
};
```

And I am getting a response here is the example response.  https://pastebin.com/4g5yTvfD

And here is my example html (nothing fancy just basic)
https://pastebin.com/JpwFLGbz

I am receiving an error saying that the client id is undefined so it isn't being sent to the front end correctly.

I have created many tickets with stripe, but I haven't received any responses. I've been working on it for days, now.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.